# React v.18.0 - Multiple inputs to edit built through a .map function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, edit, array.prototype.map

Requirement is to edit only the *Property value* column. This dynamic input has been built through `.map` function.Where only during the double click the value should become editable, *onClick* of elsewhere it should become read-only.

**Problem statement**:

1. While doubleClicked on value, all the Property Value becomes editable. Which should not happen. Only the doubleClicked cell should become editable rest should be read-only.
2. Under *Actions* column, there are 4 buttons, Save, Delete, Info & Cancel. These actions should be applicable only for the edited Property value cell and should not apply for other cells.

**Try 1**: I tried using the dynamic ID for the elements based on index value but still I am using the a common state it was getting applied for all rows.

**Try 2**: I tried using `event.current` and  `event.currentTarget` but still it was applying for all rows.

I have deployed the code here in stackblitz please take a look at it and comment if you require any input to help me.

> Coder view: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kzog2m
>
> End-user view: https://react-kzog2m.stackblitz.io/
>
> Double click to edit the middle column - Property Values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it for you

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eaomjw

The issue you did is that you are not checking any index when you edit
basically you are just saying that they are all editable

but instead of making edit boolean true or false
you assign in the index of the row you clicked
you could know which row that is pressed and make it editable only while the rest are viewed

Comment: If the property value is `null` from the `rowData` we couldn't edit if double clicked.

Comment: it doesn't necessary need to be null it can be what ever you want you want make it a special number like -23514 instead of null or some unique random string,what matter is that you understand what was mistake